# Datedif: Date recognitian/parameter problem

Tags: libreoffice-calc

This here works

```
=DATEDIF("1974-04-17";"2012-06-13";"y")
```

But it doesn't work for me when I want to "rebuild" it:

```
=DATEDIF("2020-07-20";"2020-06-13";"y")
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work because

```
DATEDIF(X;Y;Z) X<Y
```

is a necessary condition.